# Запросить индекс элемента массива у пользователя и при нахождении вывести его, если нет, то вывести ошибку

Tags: c#, массивы

> Напишите программу, которая запрашивает у пользователя 5 целых чисел и сохраняет их в массиве. После программа сортирует массив по возрастанию и выводит отсортированный массив на экран. Затем программа запрашивает у пользователя число и находит его индекс в массиве. Если число не найдено, программа выводит сообщение об ошибке.

С частью по запросу и выводу массива по возрастанию у меня получилось, а вот найти и вывести индекс числа - не получается. Вся проблема в том, что при сравнении ввода от пользователя и данных массива пишет, что нельзя преобразовать данные, то есть при сравнении будут разные типы данных.

```
int[] numbers = new int[5];

Console.WriteLine("Введите 5 чисел");


for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
{
    int userInput = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    numbers[i] = userInput;
}

Array.Sort(numbers);

for (int j = 0; j < numbers.Length; j++)
{
    
    Console.Write(numbers[j] + " ");
}


Console.WriteLine("Введите число");
int userInput2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine);


for (int m = 0; m < numbers.Length; m++)
{
    if (numbers[m] = userInput2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Индекс числа {userInput2} будет {numbers.GetValue(userInput2)}");

    }

    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ошибка ввода, попробуйте еще раз");

    }




}
```

Comment: `int userInput2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine);` => `int userInput2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());`

Comment: Поправила, все равно выдает ошибку при сравнении numbers[m] = userInput2 в for. Пишет: не удается неявно преобразовать тип int в bool. Пыталась Parse сделать, тоже не хочет.

Comment: Сравнение как в C# делается? `=` или `==`?

Comment: Точно, а я понять не могу в чем дело! Спасибо! Сейчас тестила код, по-моему он неверно индекс выводит. С первого числа должен быть индекс 0, а программа выводит 2. Пыталась поменять в for из длины массива вычесть 1, не помогает. Еще не могу добиться, чтобы программа делала что-то одно из if, выводит и индекс и что ошибка, а иногда, что ошибка, хотя число это в массиве есть.

Comment: Не торопитесь, умоляю) Все ваши ошибки из-за невнимательности, и наверно, спешки. Вот в коде `Индекс числа {userInput2} будет {numbers.GetValue(userInput2)}`, неужели непонятно что тут происходит? Элементарный английский... `Индекс числа ... будет {числа.ПолучитьЗначение(...)}`. Разве `ПолучитьЗначение` это индекс? Что такое индекс? Некий порядковый номер массива, верно? Ну так вон вы циклом проходитесь, где `m` и будет вашим индексом, ну а если нужно без цикла, то метод `IndexOf` в помощь (`.IndexOf(..)` или `Array.IndexOf(..)`).

Comment: Да, я перепутала функции. Не скажу, что спешу, пытаюсь проанализировать. Индекс пошел. Осталось, чтобы работал по выводу индекса числа, если число есть в массиве и вывода ошибки, если нет. Ввожу подряд 10 чисел, запрашиваю индекс 7, выдает else, где у меня ошибка ввода, а должен индекс писать. Уже в for написала  m<=numbers.Length-1. Не получается.

Comment: Определитесь, по индексу или значению. Я вам предлагаю числа заменить на строки, чтоб вы не путались с индексами и значениями. Вот вы просите 5 значений, пользователь ввел значения, и вот допустим ваш массив: `["Вася", "Кошка", "Небо", "Еда", 'Лампа"]`, где индексы будут `0 - Вася, 1 - Кошка ... 4 - Лампа`. Теперь вопрос, сверяем по индексам, или значениям? Вот вы у пользователя спрашиваете `Введите число`, на примере со словами, там будет "Введите слово", или "Введите индекс"? Судя по коду, слово, ибо тут `numbers[m] == userInput2` вы проверяете значения, а не индексы, напомню, индекс `m`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо, разобралась. Вот итоговый код:

```
        int[] numbers = new int[5];

        Console.WriteLine("Введите 5 чисел");
        

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            int userInput = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            numbers[i] = userInput;
        }

        Array.Sort(numbers);

        for (int j = 0; j < numbers.Length; j++)
        {
            
            Console.Write(numbers[j] + " ");
        }

        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Введите число");
        int userInput2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());



        for (int m = 0; m <= numbers.Length - 1; m++)
        {

            if (numbers[m] == userInput2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Индекс числа {userInput2} будет {Array.IndexOf(numbers, userInput2)}");
                break;
            }

            if (numbers[m] == numbers[numbers.Length - 1])
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ошибка ввода, попробуйте еще раз");
                break;
            }
        }
```